# Possible bug in route calculation for specific coordinates

Tags: here-api

When I try to request route via

https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&waypoint0=45.732686,4.931525&detail=1&waypoint1=45.438,10.993&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=gr&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=2&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=12000&limitedWeight=38t&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=6&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=2.55&length=18&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&rollup=none,country;tollsys&app_id=&app_code=&jsoncallback=parseRoutingResponse

I'm receiving an error message

"message": "Router returned no route, error: {\"_type\":\"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType\",\"type\":\"ApplicationError\",\"subtype\":\"NoRouteFound\",\"details\":\"Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED\",\"additionalData\":[{\"key\":\"error_code\",\"value\":\"NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED\"}],\"metaInfo\":{\"timestamp\":\"2019-05-08T07:39:50Z\",\"mapVersion\":\"8.30.96.152\",\"moduleVersion\":\"7.2.201918-3326\",\"interfaceVersion\":\"2.6.56\",\"availableMapVersion\":[\"8.30.96.152\"]}}\n"

ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction and mapMatchRadius request parameters doesn't help.

When I changed coordinates from waypoint1=45.438,10.993 to waypoint1=45.43,10.99 all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below request which is working fine.

`https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&waypoint0=45.732686,4.931525&detail=1&waypoint1=45.438,10.993&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=gr&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=0&trailersCount=2&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=0&hybrid=0&emissionType=5&height=4m&trailerHeight=400&vehicleWeight=12000&disabledEquipped=0&minimalPollution=0&hov=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=4&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=3m&width=2.5&length=7.2&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&rollup=none,country;tollsys&alternatives=2&app_id={app_id}&app_code= app_code}&jsoncallback=parseRoutingResponse`.

The " limitedWeight " is a attribute which bounds the truck to enter with the specified weight, in your case of route request this limitation is of 3.5t , so above this it will bound the request and so you weight below 3.5t it will work as it should be.

[image: See in route route path (waypoint0=45.732686,4.931525&detail=1&waypoint1=45.438,10.993) it is restrict for 3t limit weight.]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does it mean that all route path (not only Start/Over waypoints) is not for 38t truck?

Comment: Hi, not all the route restrict this 38t weight every route has different restriction.For example : In your case you can retrieve the toll cost route up to 3.5t only (see the image in above answer) whereas for waypoint0=45.438,10.993 to waypoint1=45.43,10.99, route request will work for 38t also. –